# How to call Zillow API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, zillow

I'm new to APIs and am trying to figure out how to make a Zillow call with JavaScript, specifically the "getsearchresults".
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? We can't write your code for you, but will help answer any questions you have.

Comment: First you need [an account](https://www.zillow.com/webservice/Registration.htm) to use the API, then read about the [`GetSearchResults`](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetSearchResults.htm) call.

Comment: It depends on your JavaScript and where your code is.  Is it latest standard, part of nodejs, or legacy?  you can look into promises, fetch, or other asynchronous JavaScript calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use Javascript on the server-side using Node. It won't be possible to call the API on the front-end with Javascript. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090659/how-to-send-data-to-an-api-call-and-get-it-back-using-zillow-com-api).

For using Node to call the Zillow API, check out the [node-zillow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zillow) package. Here's an example of how to use it with the `GetSearchResults` API call:

```
const Zillow = require("node-zillow")

const zillow = new Zillow('your key here')

const parameters = {
    address: "2114 Bigelow Ave",
    citystatezip: "Seattle, WA",
    rentzestimate: false
}

zillow.get('GetSearchResults', parameters)
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results)
        return results
    })
```

Make sure you signup for ZWSID here: https://www.zillow.com/webservice/Registration.htm. You'll use this unique id when making the request to the API. It'll look something like this: `X2-Ijdjkxlujnkd_jske2`. Keep it secret, keep it safe!

Comment: How would one loop through the data?  I get back this:  response: { results: { result: [Array] } } } @Jeff Appareti

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, you could use `forEach`, `map`, `filter` on `response.results.result`. For example `response.results.result.forEach(item => console.log(item))` would loop through the items in the `result` Array